# Is using an interface for this right?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, reflection, interface

I am working on an application where a form will be created at runtime based on data from a database.  It currently uses `reflection` to create the control and add it to the form.

With this I can easily dynamic create a form at runtime, but next I ran into the issue of how to access the currently selected, eg: `TextBox.Text` versus `DropDownList.SelectedValue`.  To "fix" this, I created an interface with the method of `GetValue`.  With this, I create a new class and inherit from the respective control and implement the interface.

Now I can easily iterate over the form controls to see if they implement the interface and then get the value of the control.

The question to all of this is: **Is this the best way to accomplish this?**

To note: I fully expect the controls available to build these forms to get to 15+.

Example of class:

```
public interface IFormField
{
    string GetId();
    object GetValue();
}

public TextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox, IFormField
{
    public string GetId()
    {
        return ID;
    }

    public object GetValue()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I like interfaces, as noted with the "create a new class and inherit from the respective control" .. *using new interfaces require that the underlying types are modified*. This is not always practical for this case. So, while I won't claim that interfaces aren't appropriate here, I will provide alternative ideas.

This first approach uses a companion object which knows about the control, and how to get the value from the control. This class could use an interface but it is not required here. It allows delaying of the fetcher (in a well-typed manner) but also requires that it's explicit set per companion instance.

```
interface IWithValue {
    string Value { get; }
}
class ControlCompanion<T>: IWithValue where T: Control {
  IFunc<Control, string> readValue;
  public T Control { get; private set; }
  public string Value { get { return readValue(Control); } }

  public ControlCompanion (T control, IFunc<T, string> readValue) {
    Control = control;
    this.readValue = readValue;
  }
}

// this is typed narrowly here, but it could be typed wider to
// the actual ControlCompanion if needing additional information
// or actions wrt. the particular control
var valueAccessors = new List<IWithValue>();

var textBox = new TextBox();
valueAccessors.Add(new ControlCompanion(textBox, (c) => c.Text));

var comboBox = new ComboBox();
valueAccessors.Add(new ControlCompanion(comboBox, (c) => c.SelectedValue));

var allValues = valueAccessors.Select(v => v.Value);
```

Another alternative is to create a function that knows how to extract the values. Because these controls are "created dynamically" (e.g. of type Control) we can't use method overloading directly and must therefore accept the more general type and use some form of reflection or type refinement.

```
string GetValue(Control c) {
   // using this form will allow invalid path detection
   TextBox tb;
   ComboBox cb;
   if ((tb = c as TextBox) != null) { 
     return tb.Text;
   } else if ((cb = c as ComboBox) != null) {
     return GetValue(cb);
   } else {
     throw new Exception("Unsupported control");
   }
}

// but we could use overloading once refined ..
string GetValue(ComboBox cb) {
  return cb.SelectedValue;
}
```

Of course, the above two approaches could be combined<sup>1</sup> - e.g. a GetValue function that use a per-type extractor (similar to ControlCompanion but *independent* of a control instance) looked up by a map/dictionary based on the actual type of the control object. If one didn't even want to maintain the map/dictionary manually, assembly reflection could load these per-type extractors automatically - oh, the possibilities and possible complexity!

Along the same lines but more general than the above suggestion is to use [Type Converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) which is quite a complete (if not complex) setup to handle converting types - even when those types cannot be modified or extended.

There are several different possibilities, and while extending controls and adding interfaces *does* usually work (it requires the controls can be registered as safe and created by the particular refined implementation), it is limited to cases in which said types can accommodate such changes.

---

<sup>1</sup>Okay, here is a rough idea for a general "switchless" GetValue. Note that it separates the control instance from the "fetcher". In fact, such an inversion could even be used to "get companions" to avoid explicit wrapping as in the first example.

```
interface IFetchValue {
    string FetchValue(Control c);
}

abstract class Fetcher<T>: IFetchValue where T : Control {
  abstract protected FetchControlValue(T c);
  public string FetchValue (Control c) {
    return FetchControlValue((T)c);
  }
}
class TextBoxFetcher: Fetcher<TextBox> {
  protected string FetchControlValue (TextBox tb) {
     return tb.Value;
  }
}
class ComboBoxFetcher: Fetcher<ComboBox> {
  protected string FetchControlValue (ComboBox cb) {
     return cb.SelectedValue;
  }
}

// This could be initialized via reflection of all
// Fetcher<T>/IFetchValue types with a bit more work.
IDictionary<Type, IFetchValue> map = new Dictionary<Type, IFetchValue> {
  { typeof(TextBox), new TextBoxFetcher() },
  { typeof(ComboBox), new ComboBoxFetcher() },
};

string GetValue(Control c) {
  IFetchValue fetcher;
  // This should be smarter to also try parent types or
  // check general assignability.
  if (c != null && map.TryGetValue(c.GetType(), out fetcher)) {
    return fetcher(c);
  } else {
    throw new Exception("Whoops!");
  }
}
```

In addition, your favorite DI/IoC framework might support similar resolve capabilities which would then just push this maintenance into the configuration. Again - many ways, and many ways to make it complicated.

Comment: The `Fetcher` "pattern" interests me but feels like a "structure" I will have to maintain like the `switch` or `if-else` structure.  When a new control is added to the list of ever expanding ones, I would have to change the underlying code to add a new entry into `Fetcher`, in which doesn't seem like a very dynamic matter, to use the control.

Comment: @Justin *Something* has to be maintained - be it extending controls, fetchers, or some more manual if/else - the difference is a good bit in *where* the changes are located/grouped. That being said, in every largish ASP Control project I've worked on, I always seem to extend the controls *anyway*, so ..

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much. This is one of the main reasons why inheritance/polymorphism are useful. It allows calling code to deal with a generic collection which could actually have many deriving types and deal with them all as if they were the same thing.

If you only have a two or three types it might be simpler to skip this, but as the set of types you can operate on grows this rapidly becomes the best option. Also, I'd like to point out that I don't deal with WinForm types very much, there may already be some support for this  type of behavior (which you'd be duplicating) that I don't know about.

Comment: I am actually working with ASP.NET controls.  I have updated the tags on the post.

Comment: @Justin well just the same I don't know about what interfaces those controls implement. If they don't implement some type of `IWebUIControl` interface that offers the functionality you want then implementing it yourself is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way (just to state the obvious...), but personally I wouldn't have. Extending a number of controls when all you are doing is adding a single method as part of an interface implementation is a reasonably long winded way to do it.

I would have used a helper method which takes a `Control` as its input, and checks the type of the control (via casting in lieu of a more language specific option) and then returns the control's value as an object.

The purpose of an interface is to establish a contract irrespective of the actual implementation, so you haven't used it incorrectly, you've just done more work than you really needed to.

Comment: I agree is seems like more work to create the class and implement the interface, but I really **didn't** want to maintain a `switch` or `if-else` structure.

Comment: @Justin I know what you mean. As a general rule of thumb I advocate that people avoid helper methods - usually because they are used too much and are too convenient and become an anti pattern, but sometimes they are still the logical option.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good and correct if it fullfils your needs and simplifies life.

I want to show an alternative way of control's value retrieval, the way of how it is accomplished in ASP.NET Web Forms itself. This approach could be useful if you don't want to bother with inheritance and if you are using standard input controls or all your controls are decorated with `ValidationPropertyAttribute` (which is mandatory if you want to use standard validation controls with your custom ones).

To retrieve value of any standard input control we need to use [BaseValidator.GetValidationProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.getvalidationproperty.aspx) method. This method returns `PropertyDescriptor` instance for validation property which holds control's value (except ListItem, but this case is covered in code snippet).

So the complete code for value retrieval would be:

```
public static string GetControlValue(Control c) 
{
    // This code is copied as-is from BaseValidator.GetControlValidationValue method
    PropertyDescriptor prop = BaseValidator.GetValidationProperty(c);
    if (prop == null) { 
        return null;
    } 

    object value = prop.GetValue(c); 
    if (value is ListItem) {
        return((ListItem) value).Value;
    }
    else if (value != null) { 
        return value.ToString();
    } 
    else { 
        return string.Empty;
    } 
}
```